# Can I get texts that I didn't receive due to no storage space

Tags: storage

My one plus said I couldn't receive texts until I made space on my phone. I have now freed space but I need to get the textsI didn't receive while my storage was full.
Ive had people rsvping me for my sons birthday party and haven't received the texts and now have no idea who's coming and alot of people thinking I'm rude.

Please help.

Comment: Consider using something like Hangouts/Whatsapp/Email instead. Those services cache the information and don't have obscure storage limitations.